# finding referrer to current page/script

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php/html - http_referer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606288/php-html-http-referer)

I want to find which page/script get request to current page/script.

**For example**

I am on page "index.php"

I click on link that takes me to "about.php"

Now, on "about.php", I need to find referrer, i.e., "index.php"

I need solution, that works on any OS/Platform (Windows, Linux, Mac OS X)

Thank

Comment: Please make sure this question hasn't been answered before (many times actually) before you post it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't trust `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`: it is a bad solution because it's not reliable, set by the user agent, possible to modify, and not always set or is set incorrectly.

Try setting the current page to a `$_SESSION` item at the end of each page load, and referencing that as your "last url". It will work as long as the last url was within your site, otherwise the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is probably your only way.

However, **DO NOT** trust it, and whatever you do, don't redirect to it within your site or you may find yourself in an infinite redirect loop.

Comment: I don't understand why you put so much emphasis on not trusting the referer URL. Sure it can be modified by the user agent, but who cares. It's not like it's a big security issue. Besides, redirecting to the referer is actually a possible thing. Sure, you may find yourself in an infinite redirect loop, but again, this would mean that the referer URL is actually crap. You may be right in some cases, but it's not a critical problem that will end the world or compromise data anytime soon, so I still don't see why it seems to be such a big issue.

Comment: @netcoder: It most certainly is a big security issue as it can contain ***anything*** (or nothing). It should be sanitized like any other user input, and not trusted. Yes redirecting to the referer is certainly possible, but not something to recommend.

Comment: What for? The user **was** on that page (or trafficked it to look like he was on it). What's so insecure about redirecting him to that page anyway? If you want to insert the referer in a SQL database, you'd sure sanitize it, but you'd sanitize the input anyway. There's nothing so special about the referer URL.

Comment: @netcoder: The redirect loop advice was more for redirects from within the same domain that you have control over. It's possible to utilize the referer, but not good advice - plus you need to have a fallback anyways in case, for instance, the page was refreshed or typed in (by a legitimate user) and the referer is empty. There's nothing "special" about xss or sql injection but it certainly happens. The practical uses of referer are very limited.

Comment: The bottom line is that it won't always contain what you think it will, and it's not foolproof by any means, therefore limited in it's usefulness. Also see: [Redirects and Referers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4350929)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```